# Javascript:open window without loading the image

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a code(chrome extension) to open any page without loading the image to increase the performance. This is the current method that I am using.

```
$(win.document).find("#img-selector")[0].style.visibility="hidden"
```

This is problematic because:

1. it loads image then hide it, that is not increasing the speed at all
2. it only able to disable certain image. I want to disable all images so that it can load faster.

Comment: You can use webRequest API to redirect all images to a 1x1 transparent pixel image data URI. You can build upon [the catblock demo extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:webrequest). There are probably existing posts or extensions that do the same so google them up.

Comment: BTW in Chrome Canary 75 you can enable chrome://flags/#enable-lazy-image-loading

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, that hints help, how did you find the extension source code?

Answer (score -1):

There is option in chrome settings to turn off images
https://ccm.net/faq/28061-google-chrome-disable-the-display-of-images-files
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPXDp.png)

But maybe better solution for your problem is adding `<style>` element with 
`img{visibility: hidden!important;}` rule  on the top of the page, so style engine will handle this faster ?

Comment: Thanks but I want to have an option to open and remove all the images